# Features of Visual Studio 2005 that is not in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

Currently I have both Visual Studio 2005 and 2008 on my machine.  If I uninstall Visual Studio 2005, would I be missing something?  If there is, what are they?  Let's assume that I did a complete (not default) installation for both releases.

Thanks in advance for your time and expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are at least some Web Service Extensions which are available for 2005 but not 2008, because I've come across that as an issue before.

However, you can install both side-by-side. Why not install VS2008 alongside VS2005 for the moment, and then uninstall VS2005 in six months if you find it's not missing anything you actually use?

Comment: The computer that I'm referring to is a company service unit Jon, and I don't have enough disk space (yes, its sad, they always issue low capacity harddisks).

Comment: So demand a second one, they can't be worth more than $5 if they don't have space for both.

Comment: @yoitsfrancis: BlueRaja is right. Ask the company how much your time is worth to them, compared with the cost of a hard disk. It really doesn't make economic sense to be cheap with developer systems.

Answer (score 1):

The big thing that bit me is that [Windows Embedded Development Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/products/windowsce/getting-started.mspx) doesn't run on VS 2008.

Answer (score 0):

The XML schema editor is missing too in VS2008.

Answer (score 0):

For me, there is a "Feature" that thankfully went away. For some reason VS 2005 likes to automatically swap two lines of source code for me. This happens more or less randomly while debugging. If I simply click on a red break symbol, sometimes that line of source code will swap with the line below it (editing .cpp files in this case).

Comment: That seems more like a "bug" :-)